# Integrating admob under a navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, admob

i have added all the required files and frameworks for integrating admob. The problem is that it does not add the subview to the viewcontroller.
My viewcontroller consist of a navigation bar and a UITableView. What i want to achieve is to have a admob in the button of my viewcontroller. How can i achieve this.

At the moment i'm using following code, which is not doing anything and not giving me any errors:

```
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"Banner Key";

bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];

[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to set the frame of the banner as well?

Comment: i've tried by doing this:     [bannerView_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)]; No i get invalid request

Comment: That is not a correct frame for an admob banner I think, try 320 x 50. Also are you sure your adunitid is correct? The code seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

1 must set the frame of ad banner so that it can be displayed:

```
    m_bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
    m_bannerView.adUnitID = @"AD Unit ID";
    m_bannerView.rootViewController = self;
    m_bannerView.delegate = self;
    m_bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 50); // 64 = height of navigation bar
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    [self.view addSubview:m_bannerView];
    [m_bannerView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the origin points of the adBanner like below.

```
self.adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner 
                                            origin:CGPointMake(0,31)];
self.adBanner.adUnitID = @"YOUR_KEY";
self.adBanner.delegate = self;
self.adBanner.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
[self.adBanner loadRequest:[self request]];
```

[image]